# Как в дефолтной форме регистрации WordPress поставить пароль и подтверждение пароля? Без плагинов

Tags: php, wordpress

Хотелось бы, чтобы пользователи сами смогли ставить пароли себе в учетную запись. Но не могу это сделать. Спасибо заранее!

Comment: "Без плагинов" означает "запихать плагин в тему". Что значит - потерять функционал при смене темы. Для продуктивной работ с ВП надо лечить эти детские болезни.

Comment: Да, я бы рекомендовал сделать этот код плагином) Там добавить шапку и все)

Comment: Если ответ вас устраивает, то отметьте его галочкой и тыкните стрелочку вверх)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала добавим поля на форму регистрации:

```
// ALLOW USERS TO CHOOSE PASSWORD
function show_extra_register_fields() {
    ?>
    <br/>
    <p>
        <label for="password">Password**<br/>
            <input id="password" class="input" type="password" tabindex="30" size="25" value="" name="password"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="repeat_password">Repeat password**<br/>
            <input id="repeat_password" class="input" type="password" tabindex="40" size="25" value=""
                   name="repeat_password"/>
        </label>
    </p>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'register_form', 'show_extra_register_fields' );
```

Теперь нужно добавить валидацию:

```
// CHECK FORMS FOR ERROR
function check_extra_register_fields( $login, $email, $errors ) {
    if ( $_POST['password'] !== $_POST['repeat_password'] ) {
        $errors->add( 'passwords_not_matched', "<strong>ERROR</strong>: Passwords must match" );
    }
    if ( strlen( $_POST['password'] ) < 6 ) {
        $errors->add( 'password_too_short', "<strong>ERROR</strong>: Passwords must be at least six characters long" );
    }
}
add_action( 'register_post', 'check_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );
```

Сохраняем поля и авторизируемся после регистрации:

```
// STORE USER SELECTED PASSWORD TO DATABASE
function register_extra_fields( $user_id ) {
    $userdata       = [];
    $userdata['ID'] = $user_id;
    if ( $_POST['password'] !== '' ) {
        $userdata['user_pass'] = $_POST['password'];
    }
    wp_update_user( $userdata );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'register_extra_fields', 100 );
```